# Is there any academic research on the influences of Bitcoin's long term valuation?

Tags: exchange-rate, value, academic-research

Is there any academic research or theories about what future events and metrics will most influence BTC's long term valuation relative to fiat currency?

Answer (score 1):

There are some research papers out there, including about bitcoins economical viability. A wonderful (a pleasure for hours) and fairly complete list can be found [on the wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Research). A random chosen abstract:

> Bitcoin has emerged as a fascinating phenomenon of the ﬁnancial
>   markets. Without any central authority issuing the currency, it has
>   been associated with controversy ever since its popularity and public
>   interest reached high levels. Here, we contribute to the discussion by
>   examining potential drivers of Bitcoin prices ranging from fundamental
>   to speculative and technical sources as well as a potential inﬂuence
>   of the Chinese market. The evolution of the relationships is examined
>   in both time and frequency domains utilizing the continuous wavelets
>   framework so that we comment on development of the interconnections in
>   time but we can also distinguish between short-term and long-term
>   connections.

Have fun! :)

Answer (score 0):

None as yet. It is pure speculation, and in any case any study of such a kind would have and even chance of being completely wrong. Nobody can see into the future.

Comment: Although you can analyze and extrapolate trends.

Comment: But nobody has yet done this as an academic AFAIK